# Зациклить функцию и атрибуты

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
def my_func(a,b):
    a= ...
    b= ...


finance = ccxt.finance({params...})
asset= ccxt.asset({params...})

my_func(a=finance,b=asset)
```

Теперь я использую много атрибутов для модуля `ccxt`  и хочу написать цикл, чтобы функция `my_func()` была выполнена для всех атрибутов по очереди. В данном случае три раза должно получится:

```
names = ['finance', 'exchange', 'asset']
     for name in names:
        getattr(ccxt, name)({params...})

my_func(a=finance,b=exchange)
my_func(a=finance,b=asset)
my_func(a=exchange,b=asset)
```

Вот так я делаю цикл, в котором использую модуль `ccxt` с тремя атрибутами.
Как написать цикл для трех выполнений функции `my_func(a,b)`? Не знаю, что подставлять после `a=`  и  `b=`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы "зациклить" функцию, её нужно поместить в тело цикла - она будет запускаться на каждой итерации цикла:

```
def ss(x, y): return x**2 + y

# функция выполнится в данном случае 2 раза
for i, j in [(1,2),(3,4)]:
    ss(i, j)
```

Чтобы не значило "зациклить атрибуты", скорей всего вы про то, чтобы создать последовательность входных параметров, по которым затем можно проийтсь циклом с вызовом функции.
Если у вас сложности с создание последовательности добавьте их в ваш вопрос.